# navigate to another project within my project

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a portfolio in react, I want to display my other projects in it, so I put them in separate folders, when I import the folder to display in the project it assumes the default css style at home, there's a way to make it just use the css of the folder where it comes from he came? or will I have to host the other projects and access them by link?

PS: I'm saying that not even in html when you have the main project folder and want to access another project then direct the link to /(another folder)/index.html

I tried to use react router dom, to do this but it didn't work, as I said the css of the files got mixed up

Comment: I need to change my view to another project without use the css of home page

Comment: Please show how do you import css now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.